# Hidden popover does not fire on second click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have this code where clicking on link will pop up a Bootstrap colour picker, and then selecting a different colour will change the colour of the original link + will close the colour picker.

However the second time I click on the link, the colour picker does not trigger anymore, until you click again the 3rd time (I assume I did not hide the popup properly and somewhere inside the Bootstrap it still counts it as being in open state).

Why is this happening and is there a way to fix this?

```
<a id="cp" href="#" data-toggle="popover" class="colourPicker" style="background-color:#20aaea" title="Highlight colour">Colour</a>

<div id="colour_picker" style="display: none">

<?php foreach(array('red', 'green', 'yellow', 'gray', 'orange') as $colour) { ?>

    <div style="cursor:pointer; background-color:<?php echo $colour; ?>" onClick="chooseColour('<?php echo $colour; ?>')"> <?php echo $colour; ?> </div>

<?php } ?>

<br/>
</div>



$('.colourPicker').popover({
    html : true,
    trigger: 'click',
    content: function(e) {

        return $('#colour_picker').html();
    }

});

function chooseColour(colour) {

    $('#cp').css('background-color', colour);
    $('.colourPicker').popover('hide');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

First few things:

I suggest you to use the `global` scope to call the `function` **chooseColour**

Then for the **popover** you have to trigger the click event **manually**,

This will make the popover disable for the click,

So Then call `$('.colourPicker').popover('show');` manually

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.colourPicker').popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'manual',
        content: function(e) {
            return $('#colour_picker').html();
        }
    }).click(function(e) {
        $('.colourPicker').popover('show');
    });

    window.chooseColour = function(colour) {
        $('#cp').css('background-color', colour);
        $('.colourPicker').popover('hide');
    }
});
```